# fourier inverse of a rectangular pulse using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, dft

I am having trouble interpreting the result of the inverse Fourier transform of a rectangular pulse in Python. I am using the function irfft from the library numpy.fft.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_on =  100
n_off = n_on

Y = np.concatenate(( np.ones(n_on), np.zeros(n_off) ))

y = np.fft.irfft(Y)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(131)
plt.plot(Y, '.')
plt.title("Y")
plt.subplot(132)
plt.plot(y)
plt.title("y")
plt.subplot(133)
plt.plot(np.fft.ifftshift(y))
plt.title("ifftshift(y)")
plt.grid()
```

This results in the following image
[image]

Since I want to simulate a rectangular pulse, centered at the origin (signal Y), I am using the irfft function to inverse-transform it, because I know that the time-domain signal is a real function (a sinc function centered at the origin), and that's the signal y. But look how instead of getting the correct sinc signal, I get some kind of fftshifted signal, that is the reason why I ifftshift the result for plotting the right-most signal, to get a more decent sinc function.

The question is, is it reasonable to get a fftshifted version of the sinc when using irfft? I didn't come across anything in the documentation of irfft that made me expect this. I don't really know whether this is the correct behavior of the irfft function or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was correct that your `y` signal has its peak values near `x=0` and `x=400`, however, I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve.

It seems like your `Y` vector represents a frequency spectrum which is a top-hat function. By passing this to `numpy.fft.irfft` you are effectively treating your frequency spectrum as consisting of equal amplitudes of positive and negative frequencies, of which you only supply the positive (and zero) frequencies. If you had a continuous frequency spectrum of this form, then the inverse Fourier transform would be a `sinc()` function centred on `t=0`.

For a discrete Fourier transform, this isn't strictly true, but is a good approximation, except for the wrap-around that occurs at `t=0`. That means that the negative-time parts of the inverse Fourier transform are put at the end of the time-window, as you've observed in your middle (`y`) plot. If you wanted to shift this time-domain function, what you could do is introduce a linear phase variation in your `Y` vector (making it a sequence of complex numbers).

However, if what you're trying to do is generate a `sinc()` function that is centred on a give time-value, this must be much easier to do directly in the time-domain, using `numpy.sinc()`, and without the need for any Fourier transforms. Perhaps in your application you want a known bandwidth in the frequency domain, but that should be straightforward to convert into the width of the `sinc()` function (with the width in the time-domain being inversely proportional to the width in the frequency domain).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not trying to generate a sinc function which of course would be easily built as you pointed out; I am testing some transforms to debug another script. I believe the key point here is the wrap-around effect you mentioned, actually that is were my question aimed: you say that the second image (y signal) is correct, then what this means is that the samples starting from x=200 up to x=400 correspond to negative times. Do you agree?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think you're essentially correct about the negative-time samples, but it's ill-defined whether these start at exactly 200, because the discrete-time Fourier transform assumes a strictly periodic waveform. Certainly, the last element of your `y` array will be that negative time closest to zero.

Comment: Another thought, is that if you want to generate the time-domain waveform, you could make use of the analytic result that is something like (sin(t)/(Nsin(t/N)), which tends to sinc(t) as N goes to infinity. Depending on how your other script behaves, I'm not sure if you'd be better off with the analytic result or with the result from a (numerical) FFT.

Comment: I was doing it with FFT to understand the behavior of the function, and that is the reason I am doing it with a well-known Fourier pair (to be able to check my results). Anyway, I think your answer pointing out the wrap-around effect together with your further comment about negative-time samples explain the images. Thank you.